# How to convert nulls to specific values dependent on type efficiently?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq, delegates

I am moving to LINQ and Entity Framework (though I'm unsure if EF factors into my question) in conjuncture with SQL Server 2005, and I pull from my database and store the output in the class it defines from a table contained in the model.

The main issue is since I am moving to this framework, is that a lot of the structure of the application is based off features like empty strings and negative -1's, which prior to LINQ /EF would be turned into a null if you tried to save that to the DB without any conditional logic.

But, with LINQ /EF, they will be inserted as those values and so require logic to turn empty strings into Nulls before the insert, as well as vice versa for selecting/reading(as far as I'm aware at least, I haven't found a way to define in LINQ to automatically turn specific values into Nulls).

With this in mind, and that I cannot change the entire system around handling Nulls instead of empty strings/ -1's and such. I need to write a way of looping through the properties in the LINQ table class I pulled data in from a select and turning null's into the required values I need, for example:

```
string name = null, to string name = ""
```

I am aware that I could use reflection and loop through using that style, but from what I've read it has quite an expensive time cost to using, especially when it would be used reasonably often, and so I believe the only option is writing something using delegates, though I'm both very unsure how to use delegates exactly (never used or touched them before), and how to implement it for my issue, I did hear a mention of using a dictionary of types against delegates, but I am not sure how that works exactly.

To sum up, is there a method I'm missing to easily turn empty strings and other defined values into null's on insert/update, as well as doing the reverse on select's, or could someone explain how to use delegates to achieve this? (Or am I mistaken with my belief that reflection is generally quite inefficient?)

Comment: the easy way is to have decent data constraints in your database. If a field can be NULL, then so will your EF model support nullability.

Comment: The problem is, for example - the logic outside of the database treats an empty string as a null, but if an empty string is passed in an insert with LINQ/EF, it will get inserted as an empty string, not a null. Which will cause problems, and so I need it to interpret those empty strings on insert as a null

Comment: How did you handle the problem before EF? EF shouldn't change anyhting **unless** you used the DTOs as you domain objects too (bad). This really is an issue of the application or rather, the data layer, not EF. Either do the conversion it in the generated DTOs or modify your own DTOs to do the conversion

Comment: I'm not sure offhand, since it was setup before I worked on it, so in effect its a bit of a blackbox to me (for the moment)

Comment: My guess is that the code might've been written before we had nullable ints in C#. Back then using -1 in the app and converting it to nulls in the data access layer was a reasonable solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but assuming you are using the classes auto-generated from an EDMX (database first approach), you can extend those classes with partial definitions and add your conversion logic there.

For example, imagine you have a `Clients` table with columns `Id int` and `Name varchar(100)` and the EDMX auto-generates a `Client` class with properties `Id` and `Name`. In a separate file (Clients_Ext.cs), you can have:

```
// same namespace as the auto-generated class
public partial class Client
{
    public string MyName
    {
        get { return Name ?? ""; }
        set { Name = (value == "" ? null : value); }
    }
}
```

And so on. In the rest of your code, you have to be careful to use `MyName` instead of `Name` but that shouldn't be a big deal.

**EDIT:** One downside I forgot to mention is that you can't use the additional properties in Linq `where` clauses. An alternative is to add computed columns directly to the table or use a view with the extra columns. Then you only need to define the `set` (not the `get`) on the properties as above.

Comment: That is what I meant with the question, yes. Thanks for the help, that seems much better than how I thought I'd have to tackle it

Comment: @user2964655: I added a note to the answer because that might trip you up later.

Comment: I still struggle to see how this is going to work, but that could be my brain running in circles. Either your db column is nullable en then your EF model will have nullable properties so you can set a property of an EF model object to null, either the db column is NON-nullable and then how would this solution work?

Comment: Thanks, that shouldn't be an issue, also in the auto-generated classes, in the set there are calls like ' ReportPropertyChanging("ID"); ' will that need to be replicated over to the new set function? Or does that not get overwritten? @Wim Ombelets the column(s) are Nullable, and an empty string can get stored instead of null (when a null is expected) and this ends up messing up the logic

Comment: @user2964655: your partial class just adds code to the auto-gen class. It doesn't remove or hide (as long as you use new names) anything auto-gen'd. Keep your additional properties simple and let them rely on the auto-gen'd code for all the heavy lifting and you will be fine.